How can I indicate to static type checkers that specific methods of a library's baseclass MUST be re-implemented in our subclasses?
I use a protocol to enforce that our subclasses should implement extra methods and define extra attributes. But I would like to also enforce that specific methods of the base class MUST be re-implemented in our subclass. Is this possible?
### From some lib: ###

class BaseFoo:
    def a_really_nice_func(self, intparam: int) -> str:
        print("This is the base behaviour")

### End lib ### 

### Start my code: ###

class OurBaseFooProtocol(Protocol):
    description: str
    
    def a_really_nice_func(self, intparam: int) -> str:
       ...
    

# We need to implement a lot of classes like this:
class Foo(BaseFoo, OurBaseFooProtocol):
    description = "I like trains" # Correctly gives an error if it's not defined
    
    # but if I don't define `a_really_nice_func`, it doesn't complain - because it's defined in `BaseFoo`.
    # How do I force all subclasses of BaseFoo that implement the OurBaseFoo protocol 
    # to *re-implement `a_really_nice_func`? 

EDIT - NOTE:
I originally implemented this as an ABC:

class OurBaseFoo(BaseFoo, ABC):
    description: str
    
    @abstractmethod
    def a_really_nice_func(self, intparam: int) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError

But, unfortunately, this does not allow mypy/pyright to show an error when our subclass does not define the description attribute.

You're right, I forgot it when making my toy example.

If you really need that method to always be overridden, BaseFoo should mark a_really_nice_func abstract. If you can add that (or run mypy on your test suite), just instantiate every class somewhere - it will point out missing methods.

description = "I like trains" # Correctly gives an error if it's not defined I don't see this happening with static type-checkers. Do you mean it gives an error at runtime if it's not defined?

@STerliakov: I cannot change BaseFoo, it's a library class I have no control over.

@dROOOze No, I get an error from Pylance (Pyright):
"Class derives from one or more protocol classes but does not implement all required members
Member "description" is declared in protocol class "OurBaseFooProtocol"

Maybe you have a setting turned on that I don't have - I can't see this error at Pyright playground.

Ohh, you need to actually write Foo() somewhere. My bad - but the error message which occurs doesn't seem the same as yours - the playground reports Cannot instantiate abstract class "Foo", "OurBaseFooProtocol.description" is not implemented.

not sure about mypy or pyright but i hope this helps
class A:
    description: str
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        if instance.description==None:
            # or `hasattr(instance, "description")` like in the comments if None values are allowed
            raise ValueError("description is None")
        return instance
        
class B(A):
    pass
    
class C(A):
    description: str = "class C"
    
try:
    newclass = B()
except Exception:
    newclass = C()
    
print(type(newclass))

in combination with the @abstractmethod that is

While it would have to be run to generate the error, and wouldn't affect a static check, it could still be better than nothing if there isn't a better way.

Except, unless I'm missing something, that instance.description ==  None should be hasattr(instance, "description"), right? If it was only annotated but not set, it won't be there.

that's fair, i'm just assming there should be a value set due to the comment there

Ah, I see. Since you're using a broad except Exception, you're counting on it to catch either your manually-raised ValueError or the NameError from the missing attribute. It's usually better to be much more specific with except clauses.

... uh, the broad except is as demonstration, though maybe my ValueError can be the wrong exception too (i have a bad habit of not using exceptions :/ )
